# the best way to control which object to create

Tags: design-patterns, dao, factory-pattern

I use DAO to handle data, but the DAO is just an interface, I have several concrete DAO objects for different objects. So I have to control what DAO I use. The following are code that a factory object create a DAO object:

```
Factory factory = DAOFactory.getInstance();
ParkingLotDAO dao = (ParkingLotDAO)factory.create(daoType);
```

As can be seem that I use String(daoType is a String) to control which DAO the factory should create, problem is, String is hard to maintain and easy to go wrong. Is there better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:
**[Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)** (creational methods returning an implementation of an abstract/interface type)

```
ParkingLotDAO dao = (ParkingLotDAO)factory.create(IParkingLotDAO);
```